# 303 Mhz Wireless Transmitter

Tags: rf

I am in need of a 303 MHz transmitter.  Similar to this (just different freq):

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534

If I purchase the item above and replace the crystal with a 303 MHz one like this:

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/RO2043/?qs=Ps7QaYwWPwweGuQ2BJkoXA%3D%3D

Would it work?  Or would the antenna or something be wrong and it not work?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I am still fairly new to electronics.  I am more of a software guy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably work, but there are a few coils and capacitors on the board that may not be optimal at the lower frequency. The 315MHz version ([Sparkfun WRL-10535](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10535)) would be better choice.

If your receiver is a super-regenerative type then it might already have a wide enough bandwidth to receive at 315MHz, or you may be able to retune it to the higher frequency - then you wouldn't have to replace the resonator.